# Access violation in unknown section at address 0x0

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, rust

in this log, my logic is completed in instruction but  somehow Program failed to complete. Can anyone help me here? why program is failing.

```
logs: [
    'Program <my_program> invoke [1]',
    'Program log: first-log : ok,
    'Program log: final-log --> : success',
    'Program <my_program> consumed 58129 of 1400000 compute units',
    'Program failed to complete: Access violation in unknown section at address 0x0 of size 4 by instruction #8027',
    'Program <my_program> failed: Program failed to complete'
  ]
```

Comment: You'll need to post the full logic of your program to see what's happening. Most likely, your program is trying to write or use memory that it isn't allowed to use.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks any amount of details to aid in question being answered and the author has not replied to the past comment 10 months ago